# Password for Manjaro

Tags: system-installation, password, manjaro

When installing Manjaro from a bootable USB stick, it asks for a password. I googled and found:

unsername: manjaro
password: manjaro

username:root
password: manjaro

Nothing works. Now I have installed several Linux distros but no one asked for a password, but instead it asked to create my own password.

It is practically impossible to install Manjaro. Does anybody know that password ?

Thx

Comment: According to page 48 in the [Manjaro User's Guide](http://cznic.dl.osdn.jp/storage/g/m/ma/manjaro/Manjaro-User-Guide.pdf) (PDF link), the installer should have asked you to enter a new username and password. Is it possible that you skipped over this step by mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You can get into the machine by editing the init line from grub, this can be done by pressing “e” at the boot menu. Use your arrow keys to go to the init line Set it to init=/bin/bash. If the init line doesnt exist. Add it on the end. This will get you a root shell on the box.  Then change it with passwd.

Answer (score -2):

Why not try this basic password guesses like:

1. password
2. 1
3. Manjaro (Notice Capital)
4. orajnam
5. orajnaM (Notice Capital)
6. toor

I would generally try these six for most distro's, however, changing the distro's name.